# Delay at deleted websites in the navigation

Tags: navigation

I have a global navigation where the the subsites are appearing. If I delete a subsite sometimes it happens that the deleted subsite still appears in the navigation.

How does the navigation works? Is there a job, which starts every n minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably either object cache or output cache. You can disable those independently from Site Settings to see which one it is in your case.

You should be able to implement an event handler that flushes at least the output cache when a site is deleted, but I would perhaps try to reason with the other party and explain that benefits of using caching don't come without a price.

Answer (score 0):

At a command prompt: IISRESET /NOFORCE

Restarting IIS will likely fix you up.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". See [answer] for general guidelines.